# Envio de Email de tag Favorita

Tags: novo-recurso

Estou cadastrado na tag `REGEX` para receber e-mail, me notificando sobre novas perguntas que tenham essa tag.

A questão é que muitas vezes por estar frequentando o site, eu respondo a pergunta e um tempo depois eu recebo o e-mail sobre a pergunta que eu já respondi.

#### Solicitação

- Verificar se eu já visualizei a pergunta, ou ate mesmo se já respondi, e não enviar o e-mail.

#### Adendo

Não tem nada a ver com a questão, mas é que eu tenho TOC em manter minha caixa de e-mail com tudo lido. :)

Comment: Eu nem sabia que existia essa opção. xD